# Как сделать транслитерацию файлов и папок при загрузке на сервер?

Tags: laravel

laravel 5

Использую barryvdh/laravel-elfinder для загрузки файлов на сервер.

Необходимо дописать функционал, который при загрузке файлов на сервер, производил транслитерацию кириллицы в именах файлов и папок.

Как я это вижу:

Нужно переопределить метод, который отвечает за копирование/перенос или направляет данные о файле/файл в последующую обработку, и использовать например str_slug()

Кто сталкивался с такой задачей?

Подскажите куда копать. Хочется сделать все грамотно. Не костыльно.

В данный момент роюсь в \vendor\barryvdh

Comment: А почему именно этот используешь компонент ?, unisharp/laravel-filemanager" - попробуй вот это, тут есть события которые можно перехватывать.

Comment: Спасибо. Попробую. Отпишусь по результату.